# Bluetooth for PCIE Combo Wireless Card RealTek RTL8221AE/AzureWave AW-CB161H Not Working on 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on a Shuttle DS81 with WLN-P wireless PCIE combo card - AKA RTL8821AE.

https://download.shuttle.eu/Datasheets/Accessories/WLN-P_e.pdf

### lspci output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

### lsusb output

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05e3:0723 Genesys Logic, Inc. GL827L SD/MMC/MS Flash Card Reader
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The BCM is a plugin usb BT adapter I'm using because the RTLBT adapter is not working.

### kernel BT drivers

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btrtl.ko
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8852au_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8852au_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8761a_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
license:        GPL
version:        0.1
description:    Bluetooth support for Realtek devices ver 0.1
author:         Daniel Drake <drake@endlessm.com>
srcversion:     FE3B4BF9C3C739ACE2FD435
depends:        bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           btrtl
vermagic:       5.13.0-40-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        6C:A3:20:B6:26:B2:D7:55:78:05:68:08:41:30:FA:64:76:C3:EB:49
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      8F:09:4F:1A:F8:BE:48:77:D1:71:C6:75:8C:C5:5C:86:CF:72:5D:59:
        69:E5:DC:65:27:56:4F:E4:E4:95:74:27:E2:40:A6:A8:1F:88:E9:B2:
        71:B0:BA:1A:8D:93:04:71:57:BE:59:A1:E5:FC:FF:7D:53:B0:25:1C:
        32:28:94:43:1B:E7:9A:46:37:0E:A8:1C:8B:B5:4F:5E:17:71:DB:51:
        AC:EC:EB:35:15:C6:E6:08:72:A4:BE:00:90:A2:65:EC:DA:81:07:40:
        1E:EA:89:2E:DB:16:B5:71:E6:2C:2D:5F:97:DD:B9:82:FA:F3:50:2C:
        00:5E:42:DC:61:05:6A:3E:BA:10:D8:E5:ED:A8:C0:BB:BF:5E:EB:17:
        E4:BE:1E:EA:66:3E:A0:25:25:2E:C6:D5:18:B9:1A:C8:4B:EF:5F:39:
        E2:F1:BF:5B:24:77:8D:B1:4B:65:6B:E5:28:DF:4D:CA:31:67:72:CD:
        89:F1:5E:F7:28:DC:FB:E1:48:3D:57:53:DB:57:B5:D9:1D:7C:76:3F:
        1D:CD:4B:E2:86:C0:FE:83:31:4F:2E:25:2A:D6:6C:31:E9:CE:35:A8:
        63:CE:57:37:0E:9B:CF:76:07:94:92:CD:93:2F:D9:93:D9:6C:0E:79:
        0F:91:63:E8:9F:5D:D9:67:0E:C7:2D:0E:DC:D5:F5:6F:71:FD:F0:4C:
        01:FE:6B:E1:9D:87:3F:9D:C6:29:F7:FA:83:F7:19:52:8C:94:54:80:
        6D:23:60:EC:A7:9D:A9:7B:32:9E:48:C1:67:6D:80:AA:6B:19:7F:47:
        96:EE:3D:06:48:9C:02:14:AF:A5:55:79:D1:FB:0D:BA:69:F0:28:6D:
        9F:B5:DA:94:5E:54:1A:6E:43:ED:F3:73:AD:7A:C7:71:4A:36:7B:CF:
        34:D9:F1:BD:F4:2A:43:02:BC:33:10:5A:2D:00:93:F4:27:DD:2B:2D:
        A8:43:3C:27:77:FC:B2:41:31:01:CD:A6:6F:C0:D1:D8:1E:8F:CE:11:
        9D:EF:99:7E:02:45:50:64:86:2E:59:91:7B:36:A9:76:A3:44:9E:E8:
        DF:14:3E:B0:B1:99:11:3E:A9:D0:26:01:B9:D9:05:81:C8:09:92:E9:
        2D:4B:40:08:AA:22:2B:5F:B6:C6:DD:F4:A9:81:A6:38:2F:2F:36:C1:
        8B:A3:35:83:61:E4:E1:C3:E3:05:E0:CE:43:FD:B5:21:3E:21:8B:F9:
        B0:9F:4E:2B:7E:2E:22:F8:BC:20:FF:0F:0A:F2:3E:FD:EF:DE:50:CD:
        F5:0E:48:88:01:FF:4D:E9:45:DA:F3:9C:F2:FE:7F:A3:08:7F:54:77:
        C9:CC:0D:CD:24:E2:E0:E4:76:B7:9E:B0
```

### dmesg | grep -i rtl

```
[    0.696342] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g, 80:ee:73:96:9e:d4, XID 4c0, IRQ 31
[    0.711729] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth1: RTL8168g/8111g, 80:ee:73:96:9e:d5, XID 4c0, IRQ 32
[    1.904395] rtl8821ae 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    1.922462] rtl8821ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_29.bin
[    1.922467] rtl8821ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin
[    1.924268] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    1.924503] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[    1.929538] rtl8821ae 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[    3.390201] btrtl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.390204] btrtl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.390227] btrtl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

I've done extensive googling, installed various git repos, but nothing so far works and many of the posts are old and stale.

Can anyone share how to get the PCIE RTL8821AE BT module up and running with Ubuntu?
Thanks,
FB

### following updates to 5.13.0-41-generic

```
# modinfo btrtl
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/updates/dkms/btrtl.ko
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8761a_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
firmware:       rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
license:        GPL
version:        0.1.1
description:    Bluetooth support for Realtek devices ver 0.1.1
author:         Daniel Drake <drake@endlessm.com>
srcversion:     0EFA03EC36186DFB6EA7C24
depends:        bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
name:           btrtl
vermagic:       5.13.0-41-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         DS81-1 Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        2B:47:74:CE:1D:C6:93:9D:6A:59:3D:1C:01:74:A7:20:F4:64:74:ED
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      90:E7:07:53:1E:6D:24:28:06:93:C1:20:EE:63:80:14:D3:41:33:6A:
        39:B1:F9:7A:59:15:12:B7:48:4F:66:1D:AC:51:AA:73:47:E7:BB:02:
        9E:7E:84:19:8C:D2:82:3B:62:1B:E5:9D:37:1C:1A:5F:1D:C2:BF:59:
        7F:09:62:36:38:25:20:B9:21:F5:3C:AB:3A:AB:19:D9:D0:68:5A:D8:
        BC:4E:22:94:F4:B1:F7:36:4D:5E:66:16:ED:CB:95:0A:25:96:E1:8F:
        C7:1E:C2:AC:5A:03:9F:FB:24:E2:FD:EA:B7:3E:17:23:5D:8B:9C:F3:
        0B:BF:23:38:0E:7E:9E:8D:E2:B1:3F:36:85:11:CF:BE:CB:AE:C9:DB:
        C9:4A:72:49:19:F0:C8:71:13:FB:26:8C:0E:88:B3:8E:92:9B:BA:1D:
        89:25:2F:E8:A8:1F:7F:05:CD:FE:91:9F:E3:F4:CE:FE:F9:83:48:72:
        F0:62:A5:8C:17:E9:AA:23:E9:22:6E:5B:57:26:F1:9E:10:94:60:B5:
        EF:AC:A9:A0:A5:E2:74:13:AD:28:48:1B:78:29:C8:D1:C0:68:BD:30:
        5E:E5:4B:1E:0C:2D:DF:1D:DE:C6:D6:B5:6C:86:DC:2C:91:9D:76:68:
        0D:58:70:3A:80:E7:E5:18:78:5E:69:D5:4F:64:3E:42
# dmesg | grep -i rtl
[    0.696298] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g, 80:ee:73:96:9e:d4, XID 4c0, IRQ 31
[    0.712313] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth1: RTL8168g/8111g, 80:ee:73:96:9e:d5, XID 4c0, IRQ 32
[    1.892262] rtl8821ae 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    1.910355] rtl8821ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_29.bin
[    1.910362] rtl8821ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin
[    1.912935] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    1.913335] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[    1.921970] rtl8821ae 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[    3.510249] btrtl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.510270] btrtl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
#
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep -i rtl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: see above edits.    [    3.390201] btrtl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.390204] btrtl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.390227] btrtl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel